# Is it acceptable to ditch the Repository pattern in a layered architecture?

Tags: architecture, repository-pattern

My app is using this kind of layered architecture:

`Controller > Service > Repository > Data Mapper > Persistence`

Often I notice that my service methods are just directly calling repository methods without "doing anything else" to them. E.g.,

```
Class UserRepo
{
    // ...

    public function getUser($id)
    {
        return $this->dataMapper->findOne($id);
    }
}

class UserService
{
    // ...

    public function getUser($id)
    {
        return $this->userRepo->getUser($id);
    } 
}
```

I notice this kind of scenario is prevalent all throughout the app, where the service method doesn't do anything special and just calls the repository method. Although, there are still some cases where the service method actually does some business logic before it calls the repo.

Now I thought I could some time by ditching the repository pattern and just inject the data mapper directory to the service classes. E.g.,

```
class UserService
{
    // ...

    public function getUser($id)
    {
        return $this->dataMapper->findOne($id);
    } 
}
```

My question is, is it acceptable to ditch the `repository` pattern and just use the `data mapper` directly in the `service` class?

Comment: Yes, totally acceptable, why not?

Comment: or the datamapper or the service

Comment: Down-votes, what's wrong with the question so I can rephrase it, thanks.

Comment: ask a question on Reddit, it is better.

Answer (score 4):

You can't "ditch the repository pattern" if all your classes are repositories despite the naming.

Here it looks like both your datamapper and service are simply repositories. Flatten them out and call it a repository.

Or lose the service layer. If it has no logic you don't have a service.

The purpose of a layered design is to separate out parts of your code by responsibility. If your codes only responsiblity is to return domain objects from persistence. Then your code *is* a repository

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If I remove the service layer how can services communicate with another service?

Comment: in your example they dont

Comment: In the example I just tried to demonstrate where my concern is but the whole system communicate through services, so `service X` doesn't directly use `repository Y`. Given that, what do you recommend?

Comment: in your example you could just put the repo in the controller